# Export the Subs and Functions in a Visual Basic Solution

Tags: visual-studio, function, subroutine, tolist

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to list out all of the functions and subroutines within a Visual basic Solution?

The short and tall of it is, I have to list out all of the commands in my program and there are literally hundreds of them now and no part of me wants to sit and rifle through the code for every single one.

Any ideas?

Comment: which subs and funcs, are they under single module/class file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open all modules, classes and forms from the project as text files, and make a loop going through all the files, searching for "Sub" and "Function"  and listing them.